# How to sum up at a lower granularity?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I created a DAX table. The granularity of the table from low to high is Expiry_Date_Year_Month, Expiry_Member_Type, Renewal_Channel. Below the DAX code.

```
MemberRenewChannel =
UNION(
summarize(
SELECTCOLUMNS(MemberRenew,
, "Expiry_Date_Year_Month", MemberRenew[Expiry_Date_Year_Month]
, "Expiry_Member_Type", MemberRenew[Expiry_Member_Type]
, "Renewal_Channel", MemberRenew[Renewal_Channel]
),
[Expiry_Date_Year_Month], [Expiry_Member_Type], [Renewal_Channel]
, "Measure", "Renewal"
, "Value", SUM(MemberRenew[Renewal])
), -- Renewal
summarize(
SELECTCOLUMNS(MemberRenew,
, "Expiry_Date_Year_Month", MemberRenew[Expiry_Date_Year_Month]
, "Expiry_Member_Type", MemberRenew[Expiry_Member_Type]
, "Renewal_Channel", MemberRenew[Renewal_Channel]
),
[Expiry_Date_Year_Month], [Expiry_Member_Type], [Renewal_Channel]
, "Measure", "Number_of_Record"
, "Value", calculate(sum(MemberRenew[Renewal]), all(MemberRenew[Expiry_Date_Year_Month], MemberRenew[Expiry_Member_Type] ) )

) -- Number_of_Record
) -- union
```

I have trouble calculating the "Number_of_Record" measure. It is the number summed up at the Expiry_Member_Type level. The code I have below doesn't do that but shows the number of records at the Renewal_Channel level.

Any ideas on aggregating the number of records at the Expiry_Member_Type please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
calculate(
    sum(MemberRenew[Renewal]),
    all(MemberRenew[Expiry_Date_Year_Month], MemberRenew[Expiry_Member_Type]))
```

Here you are summing `Renewal` over all of the first two columns, but the `Renewal_Channel` row context is still in effect, so you're getting the sum at that level.

Since you want sum at the level corresponding to the first two columns, so you need to keep that row context instead of removing it.

Try this instead:

```
calculate(
    sum(MemberRenew[Renewal]),
    allexcept(MemberRenew,
        MemberRenew[Expiry_Date_Year_Month],
        MemberRenew[Expiry_Member_Type]))
```

This removes all the row context *except* for the ones you want to aggregate over (the exact opposite of what you were doing).